# Why don't I get any validation errors in this invalid Laravel 8 form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am making a blogging application with *Laravel 8* and Bootstrap 5.

I run into a problem trying to validate my *Add article* form. It fails to validate, meaning that **no error messages** appear, even if the required form data is **not** filled.

In the `ArticleController` controller, I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ArticleCategory;
use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    
    private $rules = [
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id',
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'short_description' => 'required|string',
        'content' => 'required|longText'
    ];

    private $messages = [
        'category_id.required' => 'Please pick a category for the article',
        'title.required' => 'Please provide a title for the article',
        'short_description.required' => 'The article needs a short description',
        'content.required' => 'Please add content'
    ];
    
    public function categories() {
        return ArticleCategory::all();
    }

    public function add(Request $request) {
        // Pass the categories to the articles form
        return view('dashboard/add-article',
            ['categories' => $this->categories()]
        );

    // Validate form (with custom messages)
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules, $this->messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }

    $fields = $validator->validated();

    // Data to be added
    $form_data = [
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'category_id' => $fields['category_id'],
        'title' => $fields['title'],
        'slug' => Str::slug($fields['title'], '-'),
        'short_description' => $fields['short_description'],
        'content' => $fields['content'],
        'image' => $fields['image'],
        'featured' => $fields['featured']
    ];

    // Insert data in the 'articles' table
    $query = Article::create($form_data);

        if ($query) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.articles')->with('success', 'Article added');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.articles')->with('error', 'Adding article failed');
        }

    }

}
```

The form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('dashboard.articles.add') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Title') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-12 @error('title') has-error @enderror">
                    <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                    @error('title')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                    @enderror
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="short_description" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Short description') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-12 @error('short_description') has-error @enderror">
                    <input id="short_description" type="text" placeholder="Short description" class="form-control @error('short_description') is-invalid @enderror" name="short_description" value="{{ old('short_description') }}" autocomplete="short_description" autofocus>

                    @error('short_description')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                    @enderror
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="category" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Category') }}</label>
    
        <div class="col-md-12 @error('category_id') has-error @enderror">
    
            <select name="category_id" id="category" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                <option value="0">Pick a category</option>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
                
    
                @error('category_id')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center switch-toggle">
                <p class="mb-0 me-3">Featured article?</p>
                <input class="mt-1" type="checkbox" name="featured" id="featured">
                <label class="px-1" for="featured">{{ __('Toggle') }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="image" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Article image') }}</label>
    
        <div class="col-md-12 @error('image') has-error @enderror">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="file" value="{{ old('image') }}" class="file-upload-btn">
    
            @error('image')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="content" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Content') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-12 @error('content') has-error @enderror">

            <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control @error('content') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Content" cols="30" rows="6">{{ old('content') }}</textarea>

            @error('content')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('Save') }}
                    </button>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The routes:

```
// Article routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'articles'], function() {
  Route::get('/', [ArticleController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.articles');
  Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/add', [ArticleController::class, 'add'])->name('dashboard.articles.add');
  Route::get('/delete/{id}', [ArticleController::class, 'delete'])->name('dashboard.articles.delete');
});
```

##### Why does my form fail to validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `public function add()` starts with a return statement.

The rest of the code is irrelevant since you return from the function at this point.